# CSS Styles How to make this table not fill the entire page width?

Tags: html, css

Please see the table produced by the HTML & CSS below. You can see a screenshot of it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7yszk2v7jlwdxr/Screenshot%202013-12-17%2012.58.00.png

My question is how to make sure this table only takes up the horizontal space it needs -- not the entire width of the page? It seems like a very simple question: Just remove the "width: 100%;" in line #5. However, if you that you will see it screws up the table in a way that nobody would really want: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hztj01y3901whv9/Screenshot%202013-12-17%2013.01.18.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <style>
            .myStyle table { border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left; width: 100%; } 
            .myStyle {font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: #fff; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #801D99; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px; }
            .myStyle table td, 
            .myStyle table th { padding: 3px 10px; }
            .myStyle table thead th {background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #801D99), color-stop(1, #801D99) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #801D99 5%, #801D99 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#801D99', endColorstr='#801D99');background-color:#801D99; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; border-left: 1px solid #801D99; } 
            .myStyle table thead th:first-child { border: none; }
            .myStyle table tbody td { color: #801D99; font-size: 12px;border-bottom: 1px solid #995993;font-weight: normal; }
            .myStyle table tbody td:first-child { border-left: none; }
            .myStyle table tbody tr:last-child td { border-bottom: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="myStyle">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">My table.</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                        <tr><td>1.</td><td>B</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>2.</td><td>C</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>3.</td><td>D</td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It makes no sense that somebody would down-vote this question for "not showing any research effort". 

I Googled around looking for the solution. I presented a clean and generic question with a completely non-obvious answer that elicited a useful and helpful response. People should be penalized for improper down-votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the `display` of the `div.myStyle`element, to `inline-block`; this prevents the `table` from taking `100%` of the parent's width (since for `width` to be assigned in percentages the parent's `width` must be explicitly stated/defined) and so takes only the space it needs and for the parent `div` element to collapse according to the size of its contents. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vk7eP/3/).

Alternatively, you could ignore the `display` property, and instead set: `float: left;` which would achieve the same ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vk7eP/2/)), though do note that the other adjacent-sibling element occupies space to the right when the element is `float`-ed.